# testing usb to serial to usb using pyserial has no output

Tags: python, usb, pyserial

I'm trying to test writing messages to serial port using pyserial and reading it again using two usb to serial adapters connected back to vack "USB-Serial --> Serial-USB" to verify it is writing to the serial port as it is meant for communication with hardware,
so I have open console witch is reading all the time

```
import serial

port = 'COM6'
read_ser = serial.Serial(port)

while True:
  x=read_ser.read()
  print(x)
```

and for writing I use

```
import serial

port = 'COM5'
ser = serial.Serial(port)
# ser.write(str.encode('$GPRMC,081117.24,A,5042.988302,N,1058.376556,E,14.7,,230813,0.0,E*74'))
ser.write('$GPRMC,081117.24,A,5042.988302,N,1058.376556,E,14.7,,230813,0.0,E*74'.encode())
```

And nothing is shown in the reading console
I tried both adapters and read from external serial hardware successfully.

I'm using python 3.7 on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out
The problem was with the pin layout as I used gender changer to connect the two serial adapters
using serial cable instead solved the problem.